# How can I use PHP to check an SQL database for multiple users?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to use a PHP script to check if a username is already taken on an SQL database. The form sends a POST request with the submitted info to a separate page that parses and sanitizes it and then submits it to the database. What is the best way to check if the database already has that specific username already? Thanks in advance for the help!

PHP:

```
$host = "HOST";
$database = "DATABASE";
$user = "USER";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$tbl_name="Users"; 
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Fail:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="INSERT INTO Users (Email, Username, Password)
VALUES 
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[username]',PASSWORD('$_POST[password]'))";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to check for an existing email address, which is a method that I use:

(Assuming you have your column named `Email`)

```
$check_email = $con->query("SELECT Email FROM Users where Email= '$email' ");

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($check_email);

if($numrows > 0){
die("Email already exists in the database, please try again.");
}
```

You can of course replace the `Email` address/query by (a) `Username` (field), which is flexible, along with the other variables.

The `$email` variable will come from a form input.